# precessing each element in list <string> then store back the list into string

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Assume I have the following:

```
public static string testtok( string ss)
{
    if ......
        return ss=................;

    return ss;
}
```

can I do something like that ?

```
private string stemmingwords (List<string> wordstokens)
{
     return string.Join(" ", wordstokens).Where(x => testtok(x));
}
```

so why doesn't it work ? please help.

Comment: @ webber2ks, how come doesn't return bool?

Comment: your method testtok() does return string but for Where(..) you need a bool...but you don't need it anymore

Comment: how can it returns string please ? can you modify it.

Comment: It returns string! The signature of your method is `public static string`. Why you don't take the given solution?

Answer (score 6):

Shouldn't it be like this:

```
private string stemmingwords (List<string> wordstokens)
{

 return string.Join(" ", wordstokens.Select(x=> testtok(x));
}
```

`string.Join` returns a string, so your Where will work on the string, ie. `IEnumerable<char>`.

My version uses Select on word tokens directly and not the result on `string.Join`. Also, `Where` is a filtering operation, and wont modify the elements. `Select` is a projection operation and can return another element that was is sent in, and that is what you want in your case.